# How to display an alert with xHtml and Java EE

Tags: java, xhtml, alert

it’s been a while since I’ve been searching on the internet how to add a simple alert, when for example a user logs in (to tell him that he’s logged in) but here’s after a lot and a lot of research I still can’t find or it doesn’t work:/
I use Java EE and xhtml
Here I would like to display an alert if the input is empty.

There is my java EE code :

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SeminaireController implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private GestionSeminaireEJB gestionSeminaire;
    private List<Seminaire> seminaires = new ArrayList<Seminaire>();
    private Seminaire seminaire;

    public SeminaireController() {}

    public void init() {
        seminaire = new Seminaire();
    }

    public Seminaire getSeminaire() {
        if(seminaire == null) {
            init();
        }
        return seminaire;
    }

    public void setSeminaire(Seminaire seminaire) {
        this.seminaire = seminaire;
    }

    public List<Seminaire> getSeminaires(){
        seminaires = gestionSeminaire.selectAll();
        return seminaires;
    }

    public void deleteSeminaire(Seminaire seminaire) {
        gestionSeminaire.deleteSemi(seminaire);;
        seminaires = gestionSeminaire.selectAll();
    }

  /*  public void updateSeminaire() {
        gestionSeminaire.updateSeminaire(seminaire);
    }
    */
    public String addSeminaire() {

        if(seminaire.getNomSeminaire() !="") {
            gestionSeminaire.addSemi(seminaire);
            seminaire.setNomSeminaire("");
            return "Seminaire.xhtml?face-redirect=true";
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

There is my xHtml code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<xhtml xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" charset="UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">


    <h:head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Ajouter séminaire</title>

        <style>
            [required] {
                border: 2px dotted orange;
            }
        </style>

    </h:head> 

    <h:body>

    <ui:include src="include/menu.xhtml" />

    <h:form style="margin-left:auto;margin-top:10%;margin-right:auto;width: 35%;height:150px border-left: 6px solid red;background-color: lightgrey;font-size:18px;">

        <h:outputLabel for="nameSemi">Nom du séminaire: </h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText type="text" id="nameSemi"
            value="#{seminaireController.seminaire.nomSeminaire}" style="margin-left:10px;" required="true"/>
        <br />

        <h:commandButton value="Comfirmer"
            action="#{seminaireController.addSeminaire()}" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" />

    </h:form>

    </h:body>

 </xhtml>
```

when I press my button it triggers my addSeminaire() method. In this one, I check if the input is empty. I would like to display an error message if the input is empty.
Thank in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alert that will display only when you set a variable:

```
public class SeminaireController implements Serializable{

    public bool showAlert = false;

if(seminaire.getNomSeminaire() !="") {
            gestionSeminaire.addSemi(seminaire);
            seminaire.setNomSeminaire("");
            return "Seminaire.xhtml?face-redirect=true";
            showAlert= false;
        }
        showAlert = true;
        return null;
```

And then

```
<h:outputScript rendered="#{seminaireController.showAlert}">
   alert("YourErrorMessagfe");
</h:outputScript>
```